# Deezer authentication issue. api_id doesn't exist

Tags: deezer

I am having issues with the first step of the authentication process. I have created a couple different apps, and tried all the app_id's and they all provide the same error: api_id doesn't exist.

Is there a propagation period? Whats going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looked to be a propagation period or something. Its working now.